# Discorso indiretto: riportare domande al passato

Tags: verbs, grammar, subjunctive-mood

> Le chiesi: “È gia arrivata Anna?”.

Qui http://www.impariamoitaliano.com/di19.htm ho trovato questa frase come risposta giusta:

- Le chiesi se Anna era già arrivata.

Ma secondo questo sito https://learnamo.com/il-discorso-indiretto/ se ho capito bene dovrei usare il congiuntivo trapassato:

- Le chiesi se Anna fosse già arrivata.

Qualcuno mi può dire qual è la versione corretta?

Comment: Sono corrette entrambe: cambia solo la sfumatura, nella seconda (se fosse) c'è giusto un pizzico di incertezza o di apprensione in più. Un approfondimento si trova qui: https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-indirette_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/ (verso metà pagina, "Sui meccanismi che determinerebbero l’uso...").

Comment: @ZabZonk: Potresti trasformare il tuo commento in una risposta?

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11021/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converto in risposta un precedente commento.

Entrambe le forme sono corrette: cambia solo la sfumatura che si vuole dare.
Come viene spiegato [qui](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/interrogative-indirette_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) con esempi più approfonditi e, soprattutto, maggiore autorevolezza, “l’opinione più corretta è che la scelta di indicativo e congiuntivo nelle frasi interrogative indirette (...) non obbedisca a una sola regola, ma si adatti a un ventaglio di possibilità collegate (...) a una libera scelta del parlante, svincolata da ragioni di ordine grammaticale, contestuale e perfino di registro”.

Così, negli esempi forniti nel quesito, “se era” lascia intendere una certa familiarità o la quasi certezza che Anna dovrebbe essere già arivata (perché magari rincasa sempre alla stessa ora) mentre “se fosse” sottintende un pizzico di incertezza o di apprensione in più (magari perché Anna abita in un’altra città ed il suo arrivo per una visita è atteso da un momento all’altro).